# How does var-arg affect overloading?

Tags: java, overriding, overloading, javac

```
class Student 
{
     void cal(int ...x)
     {
         System.out.println("Parent");
     }

}


class HelloWorld extends Student 
{

    void cal(int x)
  {
    System.out.println("Child");
  }

    public static void main(String... args)
  {
        Student ref = new HelloWorld();
        ref.cal(10);
  }

}
```

OUTPUT: **Parent**

While compiling, the compiler checks whether cal(int) is present in Student class or not. Once confirmed, when running the JVM tries to match the cal(int) based on the runtime object i.e. HelloWorld in this case. So it should match cal(int) with cal(int x) and the output should be "Child".

So then why is the output "Parent"

Above logic derived from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70903492/13146358

Comment: "Once confirmed" <--- but `cal(int)` does not exist in `Student`... There is only the varargs method in `Student`.

Comment: @Sweeper The var-args methods can accept 10 as a value.

Comment: What type of datatype is variable `ref`?

Comment: But the `cal(int...)` method is not `cal(int)`. So, the compiler selects the method `cal(int...)` and this is the method which will be invoked at runtime. Don’t make your life so hard. Just add `@Override` to `void cal(int x)` and the compiler will immediately generate an error telling you that this method *does not override* any method.

Comment: @Holger I've got it. Thank you for your help.